# how to create macro in a file in an excel changing dates

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I'm creating a report everyday and the data needed are:

1. Open file #1 with file name: file1\today_23012015 for today.
2. In file #1 i need to get the items with yesterday's date which is 22012015 and copy those and paste it to the new workbook1.
3. Open file #2 with file name: file2\today_23012015 for today.
4. In file #2 I need to get the items with yesterday's date which is 22012015 and copy and paste to the sheet 2 of workbook1.

Can anyone help me create macro to this?

```
Sub Macro17()
'
' Macro17 Macro
'

'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\estillor\Desktop\file1240115.xlsx"
    Windows("With macro.xlsm").Activate
    Windows("file1240115.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(-8, -11).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$24").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/23/2015")
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("With macro.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("file1240115.xlsx").Activate
    Windows("With macro.xlsm").Activate
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\estillor\Desktop\file2240115.xlsx"
    ActiveCell.Offset(-4, -16).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$10").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/23/2015")
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("With macro.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to use your macro recorder to get some of the code?

Comment: I tried but it gets the same date to what I recorded. The date of the info I need is changing everyday and I cant figure out how to adjust the macro to get friday info today and when I run again on monday should be getting the sunday's info.

Comment: Yep, but show us the code anyway.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add code tags to the vba so it is not so scattered.

Comment: Just updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This will be a process to get this working completely,

**Practice** with this code, **adjust the folder** locations and file names.

Once you get this to work for you, post back with a more detailed question.

```
Sub Do_Something_Cool()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Bk As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
    Dim dirt As String
    Dim FnM As String
    Dim FileNm As String
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range

    dirt = "C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\"'adjust location
    FnM = "file1240115.xlsx"
    FileNm = dirt & FnM

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    Set wb = Workbooks("WithMacro.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Bk = Workbooks.Open(FileNm)
    Set sh = Bk.Worksheets(1)

    With sh

        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=1/23/2015"
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rws, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Rng.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .AutoFilterMode = 0
        Bk.Close True

    End With

End Sub
```